# Opening in new tab: how is 'Bing' doing this? (IE9)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, bing

Opening `target ="_blank"` links in a new tab or new window is based on user settings, and when I click on a `target ="_blank"` link, it opens in a new window (IE9). However in Bing, when clicking "see full size image" it opens in a new tab! (you can test it now)

How are they doing this?

Comment: what link to show fullsize image?

Comment: I don't have IE9 but I am interested to know how Bing is doing this. So +1

Comment: search any word in bing.com/images , click on random image , and u will see a "see full size image" link.

Comment: For me it opened in a new window?

Comment: i set Popup blocker for block any new windows for most sites (including bing) .. it seems they use a way for escaping this.

Answer (score 2):

I have IE 9.0.8112.16421

It opens links in the next tab.

```
<A href="http://msn.com" target="_blank">link</A>
<A href="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" target="_blank">image</A>

<span onclick="window.open('http://msn.com', 'openWindow', 'top=0, left=10,  width = 500, height = 500,resizable=yes, location=yes, toolbar=yes, status=yes')" style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;cursor:pointer;">linkJavascript</span>
```

​And only in the third implementation, ONLY with params(Top, Left, Width etc) for `window.open` javascript function, link was opened in the new window.
[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/mptSA/3/)

I think this article might help you to configure your IE9 and resolve this issue.
[How to only open links in new tabs?](http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-internet-explorer/32421-how-only-open-links-new-tabs.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate target called "_tab":

```
<a target="_tab" .. >
```

I don't know if that overrides your settings or whatever, but use IE's developer tools to explore what's going on there. (Maybe IE has an *inspect element* context menu option?